# javascript regular expressions using regex is replacing the string with multiple - characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I currently have a string of text which needs to be modified via jquery.

```
&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;   "space&gt;space"
```

I currently have the following jquery to do the replacement for me

```
$('#breadcrumb').html($('#breadcrumb').html().replace(/&[^;]+;/g, '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'));
```

I am trying to replace the `&gt;` with a single `-` character, however the regex above is simply changing the enter string to `---` instead of `-`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

That's because your regular expression:

```
/&[^;]+;/g
```

Is looking for:

```
&      an ampersand, followed by
[^;]+  one or more characters that are not semicolons, followed by
;      a semicolon
```

So `&nbsp;` and `&gt;` both match the pattern. The g on the end after the second / means do a global replace - if you leave it off then only the first match will be replaced.

You need:

```
.replace(/&gt;/g, '-')
```

This changes all instances of `&gt;` to `-` while ignoring everything else.

If you specifically want to replace `&gt;` only if it is surrounded by non-breaking spaces there are several ways to do it, the simplest of which is probably:

```
.replace(/&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;/g, '&nbsp;-&nbsp;')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(/&gt;/g, "-")
```

You're not replacing `&gt;` with `-`, you're replacing anything that starts with `&` and ends with `;`.

The `g` modifier isn't necessary if there's only one occurrence.